# How can I move page turning to left side of a list

Tags: list-view, navigation

I have a basic list in hosted (Office 365) Sharepoint 2010. I am wondering if it's possible to move the page advance to the left side of the bottom portion of said list. A picture for greater clarity:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to create a style to override the inline align:center of the id bottomPagingCellWPQ2. This could then be put into a CSS sheet and added as an additional include in your master page, attached directly in Site Settings -> Master Page, or added directly onto the view pages with a content editor web part.

Comment: This is essentially out of the box Sharepoint hosted solution. Can you provide any instructions on how to modify view page to accommodate this modification?

Answer (score 0):

Im on my phone at the moment so cant give you a specific answer but you can use css to move the element for the paging.

use any of the following to get the id or style class:

chrome's inspect element (right click the element)
IEs developer tools (f12)
Firefox use firebug

when you find the element id or class use something like:

## yourelementid or .yourelementclass

float:left;

you can put the css wrapped in a style block in a content editor webpart on the page.  Although if the style is striped out you can link to a text file with the css on it from the content editor webpart.

hope this helps.
Ginge.